# Django: Is there a way to filter a model and ignore a stored hyphen?

Tags: python, django

I have a model that is like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

An example of what the name would be is: A-123

Is there anyway to filter this name field so I can either input a hyphen or leave it out, and get the same result? For example, querying "A-123" and "A123" would return the same item. Using a regular filter I only get the result when I do "A-123".

And if not, would the best solution be to make an on_save trigger that populates a secondary "searchable" field?

That was going to be my original idea, but I worry that would be inefficient.

Another method I had considered was to pull all the objects, and just loop through and remove the hyphen to find a match, but again I worried about performance issues/efficiency.

Comment: Can you show us your filtering query?

Comment: Sure! Current filter would be `product = Product.objects.filter(name="A123")` This returns no results however.

Comment: You can use __contains or __icontains (case-insensitive)

Comment: When I run this filter, `Product.objects.get(sku__contains="A123")`, I get no results.

Comment: @popcorn That could get dicey. A-123 would also return BA-123 if you start using LIKE.

Comment: @JarrettDuskey If you have attempted certain things already and ruled them out, please include that in your post. Yes, this is possible. But if you want to avoid certain methods, then articulate that.

Comment: @dfundako I apologize, I didn't mean to offend on your last answer. When I was brainstorming, I had considered pulling all objects and then looping through all to get my result. However I thought this may not be the best way to do it. That is why in the title, I asked if there is a way to filter a model in this scenario. Your answer wasn't a filter, that's why I hadn't included that in my original question.

Comment: @JarrettDuskey No offense taken and didn't mean to sound salty if it came across that way. In the future, please include your attempts in your post so people know what you have already tried and ruled out.

Comment: Gotcha, I will do that in the future. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: You can create an OR query like this: `product = Product.objects.filter(Q(name="A123") | Q(name="A-123"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a field with a normalized name would be a sensible solution, although I would populate it by overwriting `.save()` on the `Product` model.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    normalized_name = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.normalized_name = self.normalize_name(name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def normalize_name(cls, name):
        return name.replace('-', '')  # Maybe also remove spaces?


Product.objects.filter(normalized_name=Product.normalize_name('A-123'))
Product.objects.filter(normalized_name=Product.normalize_name('A123'))
```

If you use this in more than one place, you might want to create a custom manager to avoid code duplication:

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):

    def filter_by_normalized_name(name):
        normalized_name = Product.normalize_name('A-123')
        return self.get_queryset().filter(normalized_name=normalized_name)


class Product(models.Model):

    ...
    objects = ProductManager

Product.objects.filter_by_normalized_name('A123')
Product.objects.filter_by_normalized_name('A-123')
```

Alternatively, if `Product.name` always has the same structure, you can just normalize your search term.

E.g. if you know the name always has a hyphen as the second character:

```
if search_term[1] != '-':
    search_term = f"{search_term[0]}-{search_term[1:]}"
```

For a more elaborate solution you might want to look into fulltext search with PostgreSQL or ElasticSearch.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What would be the benefit of a custom manager? I only ask as that is an aspect of Django that I haven't explored yet.

Comment: To avoid code duplication. I've expanded my answer to illustrate it.

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea of populating a normalized field, as it feels like it would provide the best performance, since you could index that field. However, if this is not a concern, you can [use regex in your queryset filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iregex). To query for `A-123` and `A123` at the same time, you could use a regex like `^A-?123$`.